# How do I get rid of Grub-Rescue?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, grubrescue

After a week of digging, it doesn't seem any of the current solutions are working for me. I removed the Ubuntu partitions but grub-rescue prevents me from booting into Windows. It doesn't let me execute anything other than ls.

 
I don't have a Windows Recovery disk. I'm running Windows 8 but can't access it. I DO have a ubuntu live usb though.

 
 
I already tried bootrec.exe /fixmbr without any success, as well as lilo and boot-repair. None of the options work.
Here's my paste from boot-repair: http://www.paste.ubuntu.com/11805577/

Comment: Boot repair will attempt to fix GRUB. You want to remove GRUB. Try `bootrec /fixboot`, followed by `bootrec /fixmbr`. LiLo is another Linux Loader, also not what you want.

Comment: reinstall GRUB manually on /dev/sda

Comment: @the_Seppi Just tried this, still no luck (it says operation completed successfully but it still boots to grub rescue)

Comment: Do you have multiple drives in your computer? If so, ensure you are booting off the correct drive. @MayurKulkarni the OP wants to get rid of GRUB...

Answer (score 0):

As [the_Seppi](https://askubuntu.com/users/194948/the-seppi) stated, using the the `bootrec.exe /fixboot` and `/fixmbr` should work. Sometimes the boot flag can be removed from the partition to boot from. Try creating a live USB of GParted and look for the following:

[image: Boot flag]

You will notice that the boot flag is on my 2GiB boot partition. If you do have to add the boot flag back, reboot back into recovery mode for Windows and then run the bootrec commands again and see if that works.